# How can I use "is" to test if a type supports IComparable?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, icomparable

I want to check if a type supports IComparable before sorting it, but I've found that checking if a type supports the IComparable interface using "is" does not always give me the correct answer. For example, `typeof(int) is IComparable` returns false, even though int does support the IComparable interface.

I note that `typeof(int).GetInterfaces()` lists IComparable and `typeof(int).GetInterface("IComparable")` returns the IComparable type, so why does "is" not work as I expect?

Comment: The `is` specs say it returns true when conversion will not throw an exception. try converting an `int` to `IComparable` and see if does any trouble.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`is` works on an instance. When you say `typeof(int) is IComparable`, then what you are really checking whether the type `System.Type` implements `IComparable`, which it does not. To use `is`, you must use an instance:

```
bool intIsComparable = 0 is IComparable; // true
```

Answer (score 5):

The `int` does support `IComparable` but the type of int doesn't, that is it, you should check the variable itself not its [Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx), so:

```
int foo = 5;
foo is IComparable;//the result is true, but of course it will not be true if you check typeof(foo)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `is` operator expects an instance on the left side:

```
int i = 1;
if (i is IComparable) ...
```

Compiles (with a Warning about always being true).

And " `typeof(int) is IComparable` returns false"

That is because you are asking whether (an instance of) the Type class is IComparable. It is not.